# Why this SQL sub query doesn't work as expected

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

So this should return all the items that are located only in 'School' and nowhere else. The Select clauses work fine separately, but combined like this in sub query the WHERE NOT clause doesn't work. It should give all the locations except 'School'. The aliases probably mess around with things, but I'm clueless how this should be written correctly.

```
SELECT items.loc
FROM items
WHERE items.loc = 'School' 
  AND items.loc NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT i.loc 
                        FROM items AS i 
                        WHERE NOT i.loc = 'School')
```

Comment: [Why should I "tag my RDBMS"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) - please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: If your queries are working just fine separately then why do you want to use SubQuery? Also, your first query will return the items that are located in 'School'

Comment: Please show a [mcve] including the relevant columns. It looks like you need something like `AND items.YourItemId NOT IN (SELECT i.ItemId FROM ...`

Comment: Yes, this is what was missing. Solved!